# Is std::string() the same as std::string("")

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a function that returns a `std::string`. Certain circumstances mean that the string is not populated with anything.

Is returning `std::string()` exactly equivalent to `std::string("")`? For example, would `c_str()` or `data()` give you the same character sequence? Perhaps the `std::string("")` invokes a short string optimisation but `std::string()` does no such thing until some characters are added.

Does anyone know if the current standard (C++11) says anything definitive?

Comment: +1, taking http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string as a proxy for the standard, it doesn't make it clear.

Comment: @SlodgeMonster: You might help others by changing your designation of a "solution". The currently selected one is incorrect.

Comment: In what way is the accepted answer incorrect? I upvoted it too. I see from your profile that you could perhaps give a credible answer  of your own.

Comment: @Bathsheba: there are three explanations, by three different persons (including me), as comments to the currently selected answer by quantdev.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we look at the effects of each constructor in the C++ standard, section § 21.4.2 [string.cons] :

For `explicit basic_string(const Allocator& a = Allocator())` :

> - `data()` : a non-null pointer that is copyable and can have 0 added to    it
> - `size()` : 0
> - `capacity()` : an unspecified value

For `basic_string(const charT* s, const Allocator& a = Allocator())` :

> - `data()` : points at the first element of an allocated copy of the array whose first element is pointed at by s
> - `size()` : `traits::length(s)`
> - `capacity()` : a value at least as large as size()

---

So strictly speaking, **both constructs are not identical** : in particular, the capacity of the constructed `std::string` objects *might* be different.

In practice, it's unlikely that this possible difference will have any observable effect on your code.

Comment: By the same argument, `std::string{}` and `std::string{}` are not identical.

Comment: @Oktalist Did you mean to repeat `std::string{}` twice?

Comment: @cpburnz Yes, because the capacity might be different.

Comment: What is the difference between `capacity() : an unspecified value` and `capacity() : a value at least as large as size()` where `size() = 0`?

Answer (score 6):

There's certainly no member function on `std::string` that would allow you to distinguish between a `std::string()` and a `std::string("")`.

I defer to a philosopher or logician to verify if that satisfies any definition of equality.

As for the standard itself, it states that `std::string()` will leave the capacity unspecified but `std::string("")` will define a capacity of at least zero. So the internal state of the object *could* be different.

On my particular STL implementation (MSVC2012), `std::string()` calls a function called `_Tidy` whereas `std::string("")` calls `_Tidy` and `assign`. (The base class initialisation is identical). `assign` is a standard `std::string` function.

So could they be different? **Yes**.
Can you tell if they are different? **No**.

Comment: No member function to distinguish them - apart from `capacity()`, as you say yourself.

Comment: But `capacity()` will not tell you anything meaningful in the `std::string()` case (i.e. still indistinguishable from an explicitly set capacity), but agree that isn't particularly clear in my answer.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't say it's useful. It just contradicts your claim that "There's certainly no member function on `std::string` that would allow you to distinguish between [them]."

Comment: I don't agree. By calling `capacity()` you don't know if it's the unspecified value from std::string() or a specified value from std::string(""). So capacity cannot be used to distinguish them. (If it did something ghastly like return -1 for the default case then you indeed could).

Comment: @Bathsheba `std::string::size_type` is unsigned so it can't return `-1`. And "at least zero" means the same as "unspecified".

Comment: @Oktalist +1, you're correct on both counts of course. Underlines the ghastliness of even contemplating -1. My argument still holds though: you cannot use `capacity` as the descriminator.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are both same. [Default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) of `std::string` prepares an empty string same as `""`

> explicit basic_string( const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
> Default constructor. Constructs empty string (zero size and
> unspecified capacity)
>
> basic_string( const CharT* s, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() ); 
> Constructs the string with the contents initialized with a copy of the null-terminated character string pointed to by s. The length of the string is determined by the first null character. The behavior is undefined if s does not point at an array of at least Traits::length(s)+1 elements of CharT.

Comment: But I don't see where the capacity is specified for the second constructor so, presumably, the constructed object could be different.

Comment: It is taken from `Traits::length` for `std::string` or chartrait, it is similar to `strlen`. `strlen("")` is 0.

Comment: Your quote clearly says the capacity is unspecified; so they don't necessarily do exactly the same thing.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Different capacity may affect performance etc (Assuming memory future allocations don't fail) but there is no observable difference in practice.

Comment: @MohitJain: Apart from (potentially) different results if you call `capacity`. Sorry if I sound overly pedantic, but the question was "are they *exactly* equivalent", to which the answer is "no, not exactly".

Comment: @MikeSeymour The capacity is unspecified _in both cases_. Or does "some unsigned integer not less than zero" mean something different than "an unspecified unsigned integer"?

Comment: @Oktalist: Indeed, the capacity is unspecified. Therefore the answer to the question "are they *exactly* equivalent" is "not (necessarily) *exactly* equivalent", not "yes, they are both same", since they don't necessarily have the same observable behaviour. Sorry to keep repeating myself; for some reason, I'm struggling to clearly get my point across.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Are two instances of `std::string()` or two instances of `std::string("")` are equivalent?

Comment: @MohitJain: We don't know. They compare equal, but both have an unspecified capacity which may or not be the same. So whether or not they are "exactly equivalent" (if you interpret that to mean "equivalent in every observable way") is unspecified; the answer is not "yes". Again, sorry to keep banging on; I've no idea why my point seems to be so incomprehensible to others.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks, I got your point now. My idea of same was same type and `==` returns `true` criteria.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: capacity >= 0 means capacity in range 0...SIZE_MAX. unspecified capacity means capacity in range 0...SIZE_MAX. there is no difference.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I've no idea why my point seems so incomprehensible. If (as I do) you take "exactly equivalent" to mean "specified to have exactly the same effects", then they aren't **exactly** equivalent - they are the same in most important ways, but might have at least one difference (the capacities might differ), which you might or might not care about. If you take "exactly equivalent" to mean something else, then the answer is whatever you want it to be.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I think the problem is that you're considering a general case instead of the OP's concrete example that the question is about. For this example there is no difference whatsoever. Yes they are *exactly* equivalent, and in particular the permitted capacities are not different, they are exactly the same, namely the whole range of `size_t` in both cases.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I'm really not interested in discussing the meaning of "exactly equivalent" any further. If you take it to mean something other than "always having exactly the same effect", or assume that the OP doesn't care about exact equivalence despite the example of "perhaps [it] invokes a short string optimisation", then so be it. There are perfectly good answers explaining exactly how the operations are, and are not, equivalent.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: there is no difference, and no i haven't invited you to a discussion about definitions, sorry. only you are arguing about that.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: `string()` and `string("")` could have different effects. Therefore, they are not **exactly equivalent** (as the OP asks), just equivalent in some ways. Why is this simple logical point so hard to understand?

Comment: @MikeSeymour: it's not difficult to understand, it's just wrong. meaningless. an assertion that's not true, with no backing logic or facts.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: There are well-defined ways in which they are the same (the same string content) and well-defined ways in which they might differ (capacity, memory allocation, possibly others). So, they are somewhat equivalent (producing strings that compare equal), but not **exactly** equivalent if, as the OP seems to do, you care about all observable differences (judging by the use of the word "exactly", and the example of optimisations that might be differently applied). A full answer would explain in which ways they are equivalent, and which ways they might differ.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: there is no way they can differ.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Of course there is. They could have a different capacity. That is an observable difference. They are not guaranteed to do the same thing, so they are not **exactly** equivalent.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: no, they can't, not any more than two string() can have different capacity. in other words, your assertion is incorrect. the incorrectness starts with the "of course" (as it often does).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: The capacity is not specified. Therefore, the two constructors could each allocate a different capacity. Therefore, they don't necessarily have exactly the same effect. Therefore, they are not exactly equivalent.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Any particular single of the two constructors could allocate a different size buffer each time. Your argument does not make sense. For your claim of difference you have to come up with a detectable difference, unless you're claiming that any particular of the two constructors is not equivalent to itself (and yes that's what you have written that you claim, doesn't it sound silly to you?).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Yes, two uses of the same constructor could also not be exactly equivalent, if they have different effects. There's nothing conceptually silly about that (although such an implementation would be rather odd). The question wasn't "is there a well-defined test to determine which constructor was used", but "are they exactly equivalent". They could have different observable effects, so they are not necessarily exactly equivalent. I'm utterly baffled as to why this seems to be a controversial viewpoint, given the common meanings of "exactly" and "equivalent".

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is that  `std::string()` knows at compile-time that it will produce a zero-length string, while `std::string("")` has to use `strlen` or something similar to determine the length of the string it will construct at run-time.  Therefore the default-constructor should be faster.

Comment: I disagree that the length of `""` _has_ to be determined at runtime.  An optimizing compiler could inline the constructor and replace the length check with a zero constant.